# Multiple compilation errors

Tags: tables

I'm incredibly new in LaTeX but I used the Stargazer package in R to get this code, however I get these errors:

1. Line 1: Missing \begin{document}
2. Line 56: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}
3. Line 56: ! Extra \endgroup
4. Line 57: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:

```
     \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccc} 
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
        \cline{2-5} 
        \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{SCAM\_DUMMY} \\ 
        \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
         LMPOS\_RATIO &  & $-$44.593$^{*}$ &  &  \\ 
          &  & (25.461) &  &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         DICTION\_CERTAINTY\_RATIO &  &  & 6.088 &  \\ 
          &  &  & (7.727) &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Flesch &  &  &  & 0.004 \\ 
          &  &  &  & (0.013) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         PRE\_ICO\_DUMMY & 0.325 & 0.324 & 0.328 & 0.329 \\ 
          & (0.219) & (0.219) & (0.219) & (0.219) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         log\_TeamCount & 0.194 & 0.221 & 0.206 & 0.201 \\ 
          & (0.187) & (0.187) & (0.188) & (0.188) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         SOFTHARDCAPS\_DUMMY & 0.087 & 0.086 & 0.082 & 0.084 \\ 
          & (0.250) & (0.251) & (0.251) & (0.251) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         HinesTaxHaven & $-$0.111 & $-$0.098 & $-$0.111 & $-$0.104 \\ 
          & (0.239) & (0.240) & (0.239) & (0.240) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))1 & $-$0.113 & $-$0.108 & $-$0.122 & $-$0.117 \\ 
          & (0.301) & (0.301) & (0.301) & (0.301) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))2 & $-$0.538$^{*}$ & $-$0.527 & $-$0.535$^{*}$ & $-$0.535$^{*}$ \\ 
          & (0.324) & (0.325) & (0.324) & (0.324) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))3 & 0.092 & 0.075 & 0.094 & 0.094 \\ 
          & (0.327) & (0.328) & (0.327) & (0.327) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))4 &  &  &  &  \\ 
          &  &  &  &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Whitepaper\_Length & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ \\ 
          & (0.00003) & (0.00003) & (0.00003) & (0.00003) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Constant & $-$3.502$^{***}$ & $-$3.000$^{***}$ & $-$4.051$^{***}$ & $-$3.691$^{***}$ \\ 
          & (0.472) & (0.548) & (0.846) & (0.719) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        Observations & 1,355 & 1,355 & 1,355 & 1,355 \\ 
        Log Likelihood & $-$340.629 & $-$339.063 & $-$340.306 & $-$340.567 \\ 
        Akaike Inf. Crit. & 699.258 & 698.126 & 700.613 & 701.135 \\ 
        \hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
        \end{tabular} 
        \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: does R really generate `\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccc} `  (it is not an error exactly but it is poor code)

Comment: Yes it's completely generated by R

Comment: You have only a partial file there note that you  have `\end{document}` but no begin.  You get no error if you replace the first line so your document starts `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}\begin{document}\begin{table}\small
     \begin{tabular}{lcccc} `  although there are some further improvements that could be made that will get you going.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you! That did the job, I needed the table for my master's thesis, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In LaTeX, your document has to begin by declaring the `\documentclass` type of what you wrote. Is it an article, a book, a report, a figure or whatever (nearly) you want ?

And very often, you declare before to start writing, some packages to help you to write. This is the goal achieved by `\usepackage`

When you are starting to write, tell to LaTeX that this is the `\begin{document}`. Then what you will write will be on your paper. But if you have to tell where your document begins, you have to tell where it ends too. This is the structure of an environment in LaTeX :

```
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

What you've wrote is the structure of a tabular which is a stuff inside the document. So LaTeX is warning about some missing important stuff : documentclass and flags to point where your documents starts and ends.

Here is a complete code to make the tabular you want :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccc} 
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
        \cline{2-5} 
        \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{SCAM\_DUMMY} \\ 
        \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
         LMPOS\_RATIO &  & $-$44.593$^{*}$ &  &  \\ 
          &  & (25.461) &  &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         DICTION\_CERTAINTY\_RATIO &  &  & 6.088 &  \\ 
          &  &  & (7.727) &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Flesch &  &  &  & 0.004 \\ 
          &  &  &  & (0.013) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         PRE\_ICO\_DUMMY & 0.325 & 0.324 & 0.328 & 0.329 \\ 
          & (0.219) & (0.219) & (0.219) & (0.219) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         log\_TeamCount & 0.194 & 0.221 & 0.206 & 0.201 \\ 
          & (0.187) & (0.187) & (0.188) & (0.188) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         SOFTHARDCAPS\_DUMMY & 0.087 & 0.086 & 0.082 & 0.084 \\ 
          & (0.250) & (0.251) & (0.251) & (0.251) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         HinesTaxHaven & $-$0.111 & $-$0.098 & $-$0.111 & $-$0.104 \\ 
          & (0.239) & (0.240) & (0.239) & (0.240) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))1 & $-$0.113 & $-$0.108 & $-$0.122 & $-$0.117 \\ 
          & (0.301) & (0.301) & (0.301) & (0.301) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))2 & $-$0.538$^{*}$ & $-$0.527 & $-$0.535$^{*}$ & $-$0.535$^{*}$ \\ 
          & (0.324) & (0.325) & (0.324) & (0.324) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))3 & 0.092 & 0.075 & 0.094 & 0.094 \\ 
          & (0.327) & (0.328) & (0.327) & (0.327) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))4 &  &  &  &  \\ 
          &  &  &  &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Whitepaper\_Length & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ \\ 
          & (0.00003) & (0.00003) & (0.00003) & (0.00003) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Constant & $-$3.502$^{***}$ & $-$3.000$^{***}$ & $-$4.051$^{***}$ & $-$3.691$^{***}$ \\ 
          & (0.472) & (0.548) & (0.846) & (0.719) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        Observations & 1,355 & 1,355 & 1,355 & 1,355 \\ 
        Log Likelihood & $-$340.629 & $-$339.063 & $-$340.306 & $-$340.567 \\ 
        Akaike Inf. Crit. & 699.258 & 698.126 & 700.613 & 701.135 \\ 
        \hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Take some time to analyze the structure.

- Each `\begin{}` commands must match with a corresponding `\end{}` commands to create an environment.
- The documentclass is an article. It's a standard class in LaTeX to write an article but you can change it if you want.
- I've added the `geometry` package to increase the margin such that your tabular can fit in a page. (with the default size, it's too large)

I suggest you read some articles about writing in LaTeX before to start by writing a big tabular. You can start [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure).

**ADDENDUM :**
If you only want the image of a table, you can use `standalone` documentclass to have a cropped table.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccc} 
        \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
        \cline{2-5} 
        \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{SCAM\_DUMMY} \\ 
        \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
         LMPOS\_RATIO &  & $-$44.593$^{*}$ &  &  \\ 
          &  & (25.461) &  &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         DICTION\_CERTAINTY\_RATIO &  &  & 6.088 &  \\ 
          &  &  & (7.727) &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Flesch &  &  &  & 0.004 \\ 
          &  &  &  & (0.013) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         PRE\_ICO\_DUMMY & 0.325 & 0.324 & 0.328 & 0.329 \\ 
          & (0.219) & (0.219) & (0.219) & (0.219) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         log\_TeamCount & 0.194 & 0.221 & 0.206 & 0.201 \\ 
          & (0.187) & (0.187) & (0.188) & (0.188) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         SOFTHARDCAPS\_DUMMY & 0.087 & 0.086 & 0.082 & 0.084 \\ 
          & (0.250) & (0.251) & (0.251) & (0.251) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         HinesTaxHaven & $-$0.111 & $-$0.098 & $-$0.111 & $-$0.104 \\ 
          & (0.239) & (0.240) & (0.239) & (0.240) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))1 & $-$0.113 & $-$0.108 & $-$0.122 & $-$0.117 \\ 
          & (0.301) & (0.301) & (0.301) & (0.301) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))2 & $-$0.538$^{*}$ & $-$0.527 & $-$0.535$^{*}$ & $-$0.535$^{*}$ \\ 
          & (0.324) & (0.325) & (0.324) & (0.324) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))3 & 0.092 & 0.075 & 0.094 & 0.094 \\ 
          & (0.327) & (0.328) & (0.327) & (0.327) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         QUARTER\_DUMMYQUARTER\_DUMMY))4 &  &  &  &  \\ 
          &  &  &  &  \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Whitepaper\_Length & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ & 0.0001$^{**}$ \\ 
          & (0.00003) & (0.00003) & (0.00003) & (0.00003) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
         Constant & $-$3.502$^{***}$ & $-$3.000$^{***}$ & $-$4.051$^{***}$ & $-$3.691$^{***}$ \\ 
          & (0.472) & (0.548) & (0.846) & (0.719) \\ 
          & & & & \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        Observations & 1,355 & 1,355 & 1,355 & 1,355 \\ 
        Log Likelihood & $-$340.629 & $-$339.063 & $-$340.306 & $-$340.567 \\ 
        Akaike Inf. Crit. & 699.258 & 698.126 & 700.613 & 701.135 \\ 
        \hline 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{4}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```