# Multiple errors after using starger

Tags: rstudio

I imported the stargazer code from Rstudio and I get the following errors:

-Error line 1 ! LaTeX Error: Environment table undefined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{table}

-Error line 2 ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \caption

-Error line 66 ! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{table}

-Error line 1 ! Emergency stop.<> ./test.tex (job aborted, no legal \end found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:25 strings out of 480930579 string characters out of 2909512245229 words of memory out of 300000015996 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000532684 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 819119i,8n,15p,118b,173s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I copied the code directly from Rstudio.
This is my code:

```
 \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\\[-1.8ex] & log\_AMOUNT\_RAISED\_USD \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 EDUCATIOL\_BACKGROUND & 0.177 \\ 
  & (0.478) \\ 
  & \\ 
 MBA & $-$2.477$^{**}$ \\ 
  & (1.162) \\ 
  & \\ 
 YEARS\_ACTIVE & 0.054 \\ 
  & (0.048) \\ 
  & \\ 
 PRIOR\_EXP & $-$0.625 \\ 
  & (0.729) \\ 
  & \\ 
 CONTROL\_OF\_CORRUPTION & 0.314 \\ 
  & (0.341) \\ 
  & \\ 
 ICO\_WEBSITE\_DUMMY & 2.798 \\ 
  & (3.561) \\ 
  & \\ 
 PRE\_ICO\_DUMMY & $-$2.451$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.751) \\ 
  & \\ 
 BLOCKCHAINPLATFORM\_DUMMY\_ETH\_OR\_BIT & 0.726 \\ 
  & (1.249) \\ 
  & \\ 
 AverageBitcoinPrice & 0.00002 \\ 
  & (0.0001) \\ 
  & \\ 
 factor(YEAR)2017 & 0.422 \\ 
  & (7.029) \\ 
  & \\ 
 factor(YEAR)2018 & $-$3.322 \\ 
  & (7.064) \\ 
  & \\ 
 logPRICE\_AT\_ICO & $-$0.634 \\ 
  & (0.759) \\ 
  & \\ 
 WHITELISTKYC\_DUMMY & $-$0.165 \\ 
  & (0.918) \\ 
  & \\ 
 ICOBENCH\_RATING & 5.004$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.584) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Constant & $-$8.108 \\ 
  & (8.099) \\ 
  & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 373 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.244 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.215 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 6.849 (df = 358) \\ 
F Statistic & 8.271$^{***}$ (df = 14; 358) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: This is identical to the question just asked a few minutes ago https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541098/multiple-compilation-errors

Comment: @DavidCarlisle close this one, shall we?

Comment: That solution gave me even more errors, that's why I made a new question.

Comment: as it stands this question is identical to the earlier one so should be closed as duplicate but if you edit the question to show any new errors that you are getting then that could be answered. As it is it is really impossible to give a different answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no I'm another user, we are both using the same programs for our thesis

Comment: for line 2 I stll have the ! Emergency stop.<> ./test.tex (job aborted, no legal \end found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:375 strings out of 4809306494 string characters out of 2909512245229 words of memory out of 300000016326 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000534506 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 3000000 for 90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 819125i,9n,19p,215b,256s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! error

Comment: @TimothyCleemput you have generated a table (only) so you just need to put it in a document as in the other answer then it will work. (The R generated table markup isn't very good but that's not the issue here)

Comment: and for line one I get these errors  ! Missing \endgroup inserted.<inserted text>\endgroup \caption{}
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \caption{}
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \caption{}
! Missing \cr inserted.<inserted text>\cr \caption{}
! Missing { inserted.<inserted text>{ \caption{}
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \caption{}
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \caption{}
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \caption{}

Comment: You are compiling an **incomplete** document. Compiling only the file starting with \begin{table} won't work. You need to *embed* this in a latex document, starting e,g, with `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: If you get that error for line 1 then you have _not_ used the answer in the duplicate question. As that says to make lien 1 have  `\documentclass`

Answer (score 2):

I'll take the chance to provide an answer ;)

This is a MWE taking the verbatim code fragment posted from the beginning:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} % <- draft option shows the solid rule on the side, according to the float too large warning

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\cline{2-2}
\\[-1.8ex] & log\_AMOUNT\_RAISED\_USD \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 EDUCATIOL\_BACKGROUND & 0.177 \\
  & (0.478) \\
  & \\
 MBA & $-$2.477$^{**}$ \\
  & (1.162) \\
  & \\
 YEARS\_ACTIVE & 0.054 \\
  & (0.048) \\
  & \\
 PRIOR\_EXP & $-$0.625 \\
  & (0.729) \\
  & \\
 CONTROL\_OF\_CORRUPTION & 0.314 \\
  & (0.341) \\
  & \\
 ICO\_WEBSITE\_DUMMY & 2.798 \\
  & (3.561) \\
  & \\
 PRE\_ICO\_DUMMY & $-$2.451$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.751) \\
  & \\
 BLOCKCHAINPLATFORM\_DUMMY\_ETH\_OR\_BIT & 0.726 \\
  & (1.249) \\
  & \\
 AverageBitcoinPrice & 0.00002 \\
  & (0.0001) \\
  & \\
 factor(YEAR)2017 & 0.422 \\
  & (7.029) \\
  & \\
 factor(YEAR)2018 & $-$3.322 \\
  & (7.064) \\
  & \\
 logPRICE\_AT\_ICO & $-$0.634 \\
  & (0.759) \\
  & \\
 WHITELISTKYC\_DUMMY & $-$0.165 \\
  & (0.918) \\
  & \\
 ICOBENCH\_RATING & 5.004$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.584) \\
  & \\
 Constant & $-$8.108 \\
  & (8.099) \\
  & \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Observations & 373 \\
R$^{2}$ & 0.244 \\
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.215 \\
Residual Std. Error & 6.849 (df = 358) \\
F Statistic & 8.271$^{***}$ (df = 14; 358) \\
\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It compiles correctly, however the table is too large for the page, as the log says:

```
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 135.04451pt on input line 70.
```

Yielding this:
[image]

Working a little bit on the original snippet, I can propose the following.
The changes are detailed in the comments.
Evidently, the string `BLOCKCHAINPLATFORM\_DUMMY\_ETH\_OR\_BIT` is very long.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} % <- draft option shows the solid rule on the side, according to the float too large warning

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % to insert the notes

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p] % just leave p(age) as the table is just too large for t(op) or b(ottom)
    % \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Your imported table}
        \label{tab:yit}
        \footnotesize % just reducing the font size allows to fit the table in the page
        \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule
        & \textit{Dependent variable:} \\ % no need for multicolumn in this case
        \cline{2-2}
        & log\_AMOUNT\_RAISED\_USD \\
        \otoprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{EDUCATIOL\_BACKGROUND} & 0.177 \\
        & (0.478) \\  % I removed extra empty lines apparently used as separators and replaced them with \midrule
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{MBA} & $-2.477$\tnote{b} \\
        & (1.162) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{YEARS\_ACTIVE} & 0.054 \\
        & (0.048) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{PRIOR\_EXP} & $-0.625$ \\
        & (0.729) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{CONTROL\_OF\_CORRUPTION} & 0.314 \\
        & (0.341) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{ICO\_WEBSITE\_DUMMY} & 2.798 \\
        & (3.561) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{PRE\_ICO\_DUMMY} & $-2.451$\tnote{c} \\
        & (0.751) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{BLOCKCHAINPLATFORM\_DUMMY\_ETH\_OR\_BIT} & 0.726 \\
        & (1.249) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{AverageBitcoinPrice} & 0.00002 \\
        & (0.0001) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{factor(YEAR)2017} & 0.422 \\
        & (7.029) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{factor(YEAR)2018} & $-3.322$ \\
        & (7.064) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{logPRICE\_AT\_ICO} & $-0.634$ \\
        & (0.759) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{WHITELISTKYC\_DUMMY} & $-0.165$ \\
        & (0.918) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{ICOBENCH\_RATING} & 5.004\tnote{c} \\
        & (0.584) \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Constant} & $-8.108$ \\
        & (8.099) \\ \midrule
        Observations & 373 \\
        R$^{2}$ & 0.244 \\
        Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.215 \\
        Residual Std. Error & 6.849 (df = 358) \\
        F Statistic & 8.271\tnote{c} (df = 14; 358) \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \textit{Note:}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[a] p$<$0.1; % apparently this is not used anywher, but I'll leave it
            \item[b] p$<$0.05;
            \item[c] p$<$0.01.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, more can be said about the inline math formatting; but I think we all have spent enough time on this.